# Get Remote System Hardware Information Using MAC or IP

Tags: c#, environment-variables, system

I have some **mac address** or **ip address**.Now i want to get the system information like hardware devices and software details os version whether the system work with battery or not etc. 
I already got my system information `using System.Environment`. Please help me to do this.

Comment: I assume you're querying Windows machines within a LAN and within the same domain. Otherwise, you're not going to find this very easy.

Comment: yes absolutely. I am alive the same domain with network password

Answer (score 3):

WMI is the technology you can use to remotely manage other machines if you're attempting to do this within a Windows domain. The topic of WMI is really large, but this [WMI .NET Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article will help you get started.